# How to choose a SKSpriteNode randomly?

Tags: ios, spritekit, swift

I want to choose from 4 enemies using random and present it on scene. For that purpose I've made this:

```
func enemyPicker() -> SKSpriteNode {
var enemyArray = [mouse, robot, drone, block, bird]
var countArray = UInt32(enemyArray.count)
var pickOneEneny = arc4random_uniform(countArray)
var randomElement = Int(pickOneEnemy)

return enemyArray.randomElement
}
```

But Xcode says to me that `SKSpriteNode does not have a member named randomElement`. And it surely doesn't, but how would I say to my function that I need it to pick and assign that random Int to an actual enemy from array?

My SpriteNodes are declared like this. Example:

```
var mouse = SKSpriteNode() 
let mouseAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "mouse")
var mouseArray = [SKTexture]()
mouseArray.append(mouseAtlas.textureNamed("mouse_0"));
mouseArray.append(mouseAtlas.textureNamed("mouse_1"));
mouseArray.append(mouseAtlas.textureNamed("mouse_2"));

mouse = SKSpriteNode(texture: mouseArray[0]);
self.mouse.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 138)
self.mouse.size = CGSizeMake(self.mouse.size.width, self.mouse.size.height + mouse.size.height / 2)

self.mouse.name = "mouse"
self.addChild(mouse)
```

I also tried to change `-> SKSpriteNode` to `SKTexture`, `String` and "< T >" and had not any luck with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in line `return enemyArray.randomElement`. This sentence tries to access a property called `randomElement` that your `enemyArray` has, but you want to get the object inside `enemyArray` that has the `randomElement` position, right? Try with this:

```
return enemyArray[randomElement]
```

More information about arrays in swift can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html).